# How to manage app server changes when an iOS app is in review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I want to know how others are managing their back end API's during the time when their iOS app is under review.

We are constantly updating/adding new API endpoints every release. The major problem we're encountering is when we have to make DB schema changes. We don't want to promote our backend changes to our production server until after the app has been approved by Apple (which may take up to 4+ days).

Currently, we set our iOS app to manual release and flip between 2 production servers. So app v1.0 in the app store will point to our prod1 server and app v2.0 in review will point to our prod2 server. When Apple approves v2.0, we copy our prod1 database to prod2, run all the migrations and then release v2.0. Once we've promoted our changes to prod2, we'll update a config setting on prod1 that will send a response back to app v1.0 providing a link to the app store to download app v2.0.

It feels like there are better ways to solve this problem. Interested to see how others have approached this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We've successfully used the iOS app version (passed as part of the headers) in the REST calls to support multiple app versions on the same server(s). Seeing as you often have to support multiple older versions of the iOS client anyway this seems to be the simplest approach.